# Kentico WYSIWYG Editor image center

Tags: ckeditor, kentico

I am trying to center image using WYSIWYG editor. I don't want to do it by source button and manually insert the code. I have tried to install [image2 plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2),but with no effect.
Plugin initialization in config.js localized in /CMS/CMSAdminControls/CKeditor:

```
/* CMS */
config.plugins += ',showborders';
config.extraPlugins += 'widget';
config.extraPlugins += ',dialog';
config.extraPlugins += ',image2';
/* CMS end */
```

Is there any other way to center image by WYSIWYG? I am using Kentico 8.2.38.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to add your image, then select/highlight the image and click the horizontal align icon in the editor.  No need for an additional plugin.

Second way would be to add css around the images.  You could have specific selectors in your css so people don't need to know any of the HTML, just add the classes within your template(s).